# Can I delete jmethodID and jFieldID safely?

Tags: java-native-interface

I have some Java/JNI code that must be compiled in two different environments:

- a standard environment using OpenJDK / GCC;
- an embedded environment using JamaicaVM (old version) / Sparc-GCC.

In the version I am stuck with of the JamaicaVM, the implementation of JNI is not fully conforming, and in particular, functions returning `jmethodID`/`jFieldID`s return local references.

I can free the IDs using `DeleteLocalRef`, but I was wondering if this may raise issues in conforming JNI environment? Is the following safe?

```
jmethodID myMethod = env->GetMethodID(...);
// Do stuff with myMethod
env->DeleteLocalRef(myMethod);
```

Comment: Didn't they fix this?

Comment: @user2543253 I'm stuck with an old version that does not contain this fix...

Comment: you fixed this?

Comment: @user1506104 I still have not found an answer regarding the behavior of `DeleteLocalRef` on `jmethodID`/`jfieldID` on standard conforming JNI implementation but I am currently bypassing this by creating some specific macros depending on the target environment (e.g., `JNI_FREE_METHODID` which calls `DeleteLocalRef` for Jamaica and does nothing for other implementation). The version I am using of Jamaica contains a very different C++ implementation of JNI compared to usual implementations, so I actually have a bunch of conditionally defined macros.

Answer (score 1):

This actually was a misbehavior of JamaicaVM and was fixed with JamaicaVM 6.2.4. Any recent version of JamaicaVM behaves as expected. So no `DeleteLocalRef()` should be called.

See http://www.aicas.com/jamaica/6.2/doc/JamaicaVM-6.2-Release-Notes.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer but you should read the question more carefully. I explicitly said that I am stuck with an old version of JamaicaVM containing this bug, and wondering if calling `DeleteLocalRef` is safe or not in a conforming JNI implementation, not if I need to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `DeleteLocalRef()` is not safe in a conforming JNI implementation. According to the [JNI specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#field_and_method_ids), the types `jmethodID` and `jfieldID` are regular C pointer types. So variables of these types should not be passed to `DeleteLocalRef()`.

**Note:** When you execute your code snippet with OpenJDK and pass the option `-Xcheck:jni`, you should see a warning or even a fatal error.